# Pandas: aggregate column based on values in a different column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

Lets say I start with a dataframe that looks like this:

```
    Group   Val     date
0   home    first   2017-12-01
1   home    second  2017-12-02
2   away    first   2018-03-07
3   away    second  2018-03-01
```

Data types are [string, string, datetime]. I would like to get a dataframe that for each group, shows me the value that was entered most recently:

```
    Group   Most rececnt Val    Most recent date
0   home    second              12-02-2017
1   away    first               03-07-2018
```

(Data types are [string, string, datetime])

My initial thought is that I should be able to do something like this by grouping by 'group' and then aggregating the dates and vals. I know I can get the most recent datetime using the 'max' agg function, but I'm stuck on what function to use to get the corresponding val:

```
df.groupby('Group').agg({'val':lambda x: ____????____
                     'date':'max'})
```

Thanks,

Comment: Apologies for the format of the pictures, is there a better way to display dataframes?

Comment: Please post the data and not such screenshots. Just `print(df)` and copy paste the output or something like that. Hint: If it's too lange `print(df.sample(5))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case I understood you right, you can do this:

```
df.iloc[df.groupby('Group').agg({'date': 'idxmax'}).date]
```

Or as a whole example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(42)

data = [(np.random.choice(['home', 'away'], size=1)[0],
         np.random.choice(['first', 'second'], size=1)[0],
         pd.Timestamp(np.random.rand()*1.9989e+18)) for i in range(10)]

df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(data)
df.columns = ['Group', 'Val', 'date']

df.iloc[df.groupby('Group').agg({'date': 'idxmax'}).date]
```

Which selects

```
  Group     Val                          date
5  away   first 2031-06-09 06:26:43.486610432
0  home  second 2030-03-22 04:07:07.082781440
```

from

```
  Group     Val                          date
0  home  second 2030-03-22 04:07:07.082781440
1  home  second 2007-12-03 05:07:24.061456384
2  home  second 1979-11-18 23:57:26.700035456
3  home   first 2024-11-12 08:18:17.789517824
4  away  second 2014-11-07 13:17:55.756515328
5  away   first 2031-06-09 06:26:43.486610432
6  away  second 1983-06-14 13:17:28.334806208
7  away  second 1981-08-14 03:21:14.746028864
8  away  second 2003-03-29 11:00:31.189680256
9  away   first 1988-06-12 16:58:48.341865984
```

Comment: Yes, this was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks. I didn't even know that it was possible to iloc multiple lines from the original dataframe using a list of indices.

Comment: @MaileCupo Yes, that's how you can slice a `DataFrame`. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

First select the indeces of the dataframe whose variable value is maximum

```
max_indeces = df.groupby(['Group'])['date'].idxmax()
```

and then select the corresponding rows in the original dataframe, maybe only indicating the actual value you are interested in:

```
df.iloc[max_indeces]['Val']
```